# What is the cause of yellow discharge in beaker during the electrolysis of copper electrodes using copper sulfate electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I have conducted an electrolysis experiment using a copper anode and cathode, and copper sulfate solution in a beaker connected to a power source using alligator clips. I varied the voltage and measured the current and noticed the theoretical mass values I calculated were consistency lower than the values I obtained.

I suspect the ammeter was not calibrated properly however am not sure what affect the oxidation of sulfate ions has on the current (yellow discharge present during electrolysis) and if that would have affected my results.

Comment: "yellow discharge"? You mean an effect with light and noise?

Comment: Post a picture. How pure is the copper electrode.